# Linkify acestream links Regex

Tags: regex

I want to make acestream links found anywhere in any page, clickable links. To do that, the only way is to use the Linkify script (through Tampermonkey or Acescript on Chrome) and add custom rule using RegExp.
The acestreams start with "acestream://" and continue with lower letters and numbers. Some examples:

```
acestream://77f890b8dbc45e57bc145d0ee2c9eb381ff8e1ee
acestream://ccba28e0ec6b5e09584dfcf80bcafa070bfe27b1
acestream://ad0de24741ba397708f6d4b0bc87a9e54a2c3331    
acestream://679b815c666b89345ae5ef64a69203dec269f09f    
acestream://bec284c6636fd196bea5fc4186de96dfa94f79a1    
acestream://d72ebe51dd14bad45ff011364ff06cd219795fc5    
acestream://8c0b73b9ba6cc1b25195d5880f7c4796f007c7da    
acestream://2dfe474e6520f6015b8d2268476059756eb02d6e    
acestream://67ffc1f4f16b6b0b1f4113f76e37b6637249452c
```

So, I am trying `^acestream://[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` but doesnt seem to e correct.
Could you please advise on the correct RegExp or any other solution to make acestream links clickable for that matter.

Thanks,

VS

Comment: And what about `acestream://[a-zA-Z0-9]+`?

Comment: I also used `acestream://[A-Za-z0-9]+` but no luck again!

Comment: How? See https://regex101.com/r/6Bmmja/1

Comment: I know. In theory it works but Linkify doesnt make the strings clickable.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. So, for people searching for this as I googled around for hours and there was nowhere a complete answer.

To make acestream urls clickable:

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for
   Chrome. **Beware, this will
   NOT work with AceScript so only use Greasemoney or Tampermonky
   depending on your browser**.
2. Install [Linkify Plus Plus](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/4255-linkify-plus-plus).
3. Go to configure Linkify Plus Plus
4. At the bottom where it says "Custom rules. One pattern per line. (RegExp)", just
       insert this: `acestream://[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
5. Refresh the page with the acestream links and you are done!

   Worked for me.Thanks Wiktor!